# Make a CSV/spreadsheet showing number of polygons in polygons?

Tags: qgis

I have a QGIS project containing two multipolygon layers: `2010 Census block groups` and `Parcels`. Each layer is in a separate shapefile.

[image]

The thick-lined layer represents block groups. The thin-lined layer is parcels. The block group layer attribute table shows that each block group has a unique ID.

How do I output the number of parcels in each block group into a spreadsheet-style format? Is it possible in QGIS or must I choose another program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps I would take to solve this problem assuming the block groups is a separate file to the parcels:

1. Add a field to the parcels polygons call it whatever you want
2. Calculate that new field in the parcels table to equal 1
3. Perform a spatial join between the block group is joining the parcels and the 'SUM' statistics button is selected
4. export the spatial join output to a .csv file

   [spatial join tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html)